# Livingdoc generates report only for last run test

Tags: c#, report, specflow

I am new to Specflow. I have 20 features and passed. But when I generated the Livingdoc report, it shows passed for only the last executed feature. It shows "Not executed" for the rest of the features. Can anyone help me where I am making mistakes?

My Project tree is:

```
|-Project
  +----Feature
  |------Login.feature
  +----Steps
  |------Login.cs
  +----Drivers
  |------SetDriver.cs
  +----Hooks
  |------BrowserHook.cs
  +----Pages
  |------PageObjectManager.cs
  |------LoginPage.cs
```

**Driver Setup:**

```
public class SetDrivers
{
    private Lazy<IWebDriver> _driver;

    public SetDrivers()
    {
        _driver = new Lazy<IWebDriver>(Setup);
    }

    public IWebDriver Current => _driver.Value;

    public IWebDriver Setup()
    {
        var chromeDriverServices = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        var browserOption = GetBrowserOptions("chrome");

        var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverServices, browserOption);

        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        return driver;
    }

    private dynamic GetBrowserOptions(String browserName)
    {
        if (browserName.ToLower() == "chrome")
        {
            return new ChromeOptions();
        }
        else if (browserName.ToLower() == "firefox")
        {
            return new FirefoxOptions();
        }
        else
        {
            return new ChromeOptions();
        }
    }
}
```

**Hooks:**

```
[Binding]
public sealed class BrowserHooks
{

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun(ObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        objectContainer.BaseContainer.Resolve<SetDrivers>();
    }

    [BeforeScenario ("Smoke")]
    public static void BeforeSenerio(SetDrivers drivers)
    {
        var pageObjects = new PageObjectManager(drivers.Current);
        pageObjects.loadUrl();
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario(SetDrivers drivers)
    {
        var pageObjects = new PageObjectManager(drivers.Current);
        pageObjects.tearDown();
    }
}
```

**Steps:**

```
[Binding]
public class LoginSteps
{
    private LoginPage _loginPage;

    public LoginSteps(SetDrivers drivers)
    {
        _loginPage = new LoginPage(drivers.Current);
    }

    [Given(@"user is in login page")]
    public void GivenUserIsInLoginPage()
    {
        _loginPage.clickLoginBtn();
    }
    
    [When(@"user Enters ""(.*)"" and ""(.*)""")]
    public void WhenUserEntersAnd(string email, string password)
    {
        _loginPage.setUserEmail(email);
        _loginPage.setPassword(password);
    }
    
    [When(@"click Login Button")]
    public void WhenClickLoginButton()
    {
        _loginPage.clickLogin();
    }
    
    [Then(@"Home Page should be visible")]
    public void ThenHomePageShouldBeVisible()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(_loginPage.isLoggedIn());
    }
}
```

**Feature:**

```
Feature: Login
    User login test

@Smoke
Scenario Outline: User wants to login with valid email and password
    Given user is in login page
    When user Enters "<Email>" and "<Password>"
    And click Login Button
    Then Home Page should be visible
    Examples:
        | Email         | Password |
        | mail@mail.com | 121212A  |
```

**Page object manager:**

```
public class PageObjectManager
    {
        private const string url = "https://www.pinterest.com/";

        private readonly IWebDriver _webDriver;

        public PageObjectManager(IWebDriver webDriver)
        {
            _webDriver = webDriver;
        }
        public void loadUrl()
        {
            _webDriver.Url = url;
        }

        public void tearDown()
        {
            if (_webDriver != null)
            {
                _webDriver.Quit();
            }
        }
}
```

[image: Livingdoc Report]

[image: Test results]

Comment: Have you executed all tests in one run?

Comment: @PiotrM. I tried to execute all tests in one run, but when I click on "Run All", it tries to execute all the tests at the same time and all fails.

Comment: It appears you are attempting to run tests in parallel. Please [edit] your question to include more information. Livingdoc will only generate a report for the tests that were run in the current test run. If you only executed one test, it should only generate a report for that one test. This is expected behavior. Unfortunately we need more information about your codebase and how you are running tests specifically. Please add a [repro] to your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thanks for your reply. I have tried to give a preview of my project. Maybe this will help you to find out the problem.

Comment: That is good information, but exactly *how* are you executing these tests? Are you executing them in Azure DevOps inside a build or release pipeline? Are you executing them in Visual Studio? Which tests are you selecting to execute?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I am running them from Visual Studio 2019 Test explorer.

Comment: The behavior you describe in your question is literally the expected behavior. Only the tests that were executed in the current test run will appear in the report.